# How to merge two dataframe for only few columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, jupyter-notebook

Any way to merge two dataframe, but not merge all the columns?

I have two dataframes, I want to merge one column to the other dataframe.

My data like this

```
In [1]: left = pd.DataFrame({'key1':['a','b','c'], 'key2':['1','2','3'], 'v1':['january','january','january']}, index=[0,5,8]); left
Out[1]: 
   key1 key2         v1
0   a      1    january
5   b      2    january
8   c      3    january

In [2]: right = pd.DataFrame({'key1':['a','b','c'], 'key2':['1','2','3'], 'v1':['1<0xA4EB>','1<0xA4EB>','1<0xA4EB>'], 'new_value':[23,346,435]}); right
Out[2]: 
    key1    key2        v1    new_value
0   a       1     1<0xA4EB>         23
1   b       2     1<0xA4EB>        346
2   c       3     1<0xA4EB>        435

In [3]: pd.merge(left, right[['key1', 'key2', 'new_value']], on=['key1', 'key2'])
Out[3]:
    key1  key2       v1     new_value
0   a     1     january           23
1   b     2     january          346
2   c     3     january          435
```

I select the key column and new column, then merge them.

But I think this way is not smart. I want to find more easier way, if any one know about this please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is smart way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it appears as if you simply want to add a new column to one of the dataframes. If that's  the case, why don't you just attach the column that you wanted to dataframe 1, and set the index of date frame 2 equal to the dataframe 1 index, or create a copy of dataframe2 and reindex it? Here  is an example where I simply attach the column that you want in df2 to df1. (Note that I did not fully copy your code from df2 in order to save time, but you will get the concept):

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'key1':['a','b','c'], 'key2':['1','2','3'], 'v1':['january','january', 'january']}, index=[0, 5, 8])
right = pd.DataFrame({'new_value': [23, 346, 435]})

copy = right.index = left.index
left['new_value'] = right['new_value']
print(left)
```

And here is your output:

```
     key1 key2       v1  new_value
 0    a    1  january         23
 5    b    2  january        346
 8    c    3  january        435
```

I felt as if you might want this as a potential option in order to keep your indexes from df1. Your solution works, but this is simply a way to keep your indexes in order for that first dataframe if you need them in a specific order for some reason.

Comment: I think this is the another great way, thanks you. 
But when I use `left['new_value'] = right['new_value']` 
 it show me this `C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy  `
will it impact anything?

Comment: @JoyWang it appears to just be a warning, but your code will still run. I was just using an ide, so didn’t get the same warning message